# Setting the OS X property apple.awt.UIElement has no effect

Tags: java, macos

I'm making a program that should only exist in the System Tray, and have seen online that setting the `apple.awt.UIElement` to `true` should do this. Running the jar file with my program, setting the JVM argument, works and no icon appears in the dock.

```
java -jar -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true music.jar
```

But when I try to set this property from the program itself, using `System.setProperty()`, it doesn't work. The property does get set to true (checked via `System.getProperty()`), but the java icon appears in the dock anyway. The code I use is:

```
System.setProperty("apple.awt.UIElement", "true");
```

I was thinking of just making the whole program headless, but haven't found a way to use the System Tray without AWT (which fails in headless mode), so I was wondering why setting the property from the program has no effect, even though the property does get set to `true`?

Comment: Perhaps you set this property too late. Could you when you set this parameter and when you instanciate awt components?

Comment: I'm currently setting it at the beginning of the program, but I've tried virtually every location in code.

Comment: And what about the awt components? If some of them are not instanciated by a `new` command it means that they are probably instanciated before your the `main` method starts.

Comment: Yes! Removed the `static` property from 2 `Image`s I was initialising, now calling the `setProperty()` method in main before the constructor. If you write a full answer I'd be happy to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("apple.awt.UIElement", "true");
```

at the very beginning in main works fine for me!